# Windows Server 2016 unpredictable static routes

Tags: windows, networking, routing, ipv4, static-routes

I am configuring routes on a Windows Server 2016 machine.

I've already set up a Lan to Lan VPN as follows on a DrayTek router:

```
Local network: 10.23.42.96/29

Remote networks: 10.41.73.0/24, 10.41.86.128/28
```

which is online and working. The network interface on the machine has two IPs:

```
IPv4 address. . . . . . . . : 10.23.42.98
Subnet mask . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.248
IPv4 address . . . . . . .  : 10.123.11.200
Subnet mask . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default gateway . . . . . . : 10.123.11.254
```

My goal is to set `10.23.42.97` as the gateway for all the traffic going to the two remote networks I listed before.
I added three static routes with those commands:

```
route -p ADD 10.41.86.128 MASK 255.255.255.240 10.23.42.97 IF 17
route -p ADD 10.41.73.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 10.23.42.97 IF 17
route -p ADD 10.23.42.96  MASK 255.255.255.248 10.23.42.97 IF 17
```

and this is the output of `route -p print` command:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> route -p print
===========================================================================
Interface list
  2...98 f2 b3 39 d1 de ......Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet #3
 15...98 f2 b3 39 d1 dd ......Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet
 16...98 f2 b3 39 d1 df ......Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet #2
 17...98 f2 b3 39 d1 dc ......Microsoft Network Adapter Multiplexor Driver
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 11...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
 10...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
 14...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
===========================================================================

IPv4 route table
===========================================================================
Active routes:
     Network address          Mask          Gateway     Interface   Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    10.123.11.254      10.23.42.98    281
      10.23.42.96  255.255.255.248      10.23.42.97      10.23.42.98     26
      10.23.42.98  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.23.42.98    281
       10.41.73.0    255.255.255.0      10.23.42.97      10.23.42.98     26
     10.41.86.128  255.255.255.240      10.23.42.97      10.23.42.98     26
      10.123.11.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       10.23.42.98    281
    10.123.11.200  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.23.42.98    281
    10.123.11.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.23.42.98    281
     10.123.251.0    255.255.255.0         On-link    10.123.251.250    281
   10.123.251.250  255.255.255.255         On-link    10.123.251.250    281
   10.123.251.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    10.123.251.250    281
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      169.254.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link    169.254.161.92    281
   169.254.161.92  255.255.255.255         On-link    169.254.161.92    281
  169.254.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    169.254.161.92    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    10.123.251.250    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    169.254.161.92    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       10.23.42.98    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    10.123.251.250    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    169.254.161.92    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.23.42.98    281
===========================================================================
Permanent routes:
   Network address            Mask          gateway  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    10.123.11.254  Default
     10.41.86.128  255.255.255.240      10.23.42.97       1
       10.41.73.0    255.255.255.0      10.23.42.97       1
      10.23.42.96  255.255.255.248      10.23.42.97       1
===========================================================================
```

and `route print` command:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> route print
===========================================================================
Interface list
  2...98 f2 b3 39 d1 de ......Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet #3
 15...98 f2 b3 39 d1 dd ......Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet
 16...98 f2 b3 39 d1 df ......Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet #2
 17...98 f2 b3 39 d1 dc ......Microsoft Network Adapter Multiplexor Driver
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 11...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
 10...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
 14...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
===========================================================================

IPv4 route table
===========================================================================
Active routes:
     Network address            Mask          Gateway     Interface   Metric 
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    10.123.11.254      10.23.42.98    281
      10.23.42.96  255.255.255.248      10.23.42.97      10.23.42.98     26
      10.23.42.98  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.23.42.98    281
       10.41.73.0    255.255.255.0      10.23.42.97      10.23.42.98     26
     10.41.86.128  255.255.255.240      10.23.42.97      10.23.42.98     26
      10.123.11.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       10.23.42.98    281
    10.123.11.200  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.23.42.98    281
    10.123.11.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.23.42.98    281
     10.123.251.0    255.255.255.0         On-link    10.123.251.250    281
   10.123.251.250  255.255.255.255         On-link    10.123.251.250    281
   10.123.251.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    10.123.251.250    281
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      169.254.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link    169.254.161.92    281
   169.254.161.92  255.255.255.255         On-link    169.254.161.92    281
  169.254.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    169.254.161.92    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    10.123.251.250    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    169.254.161.92    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       10.23.42.98    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    10.123.251.250    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    169.254.161.92    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.23.42.98    281
===========================================================================
permanent routes:
   Network address            Mask     Gateway        Metric
           0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    10.123.11.254  Default
     10.41.86.128  255.255.255.240      10.23.42.97       1
       10.41.73.0    255.255.255.0      10.23.42.97       1
      10.23.42.96  255.255.255.248      10.23.42.97       1
===========================================================================
```

The main problem is that the connection seems to be very unstable and unpredictable. If I run, for example `tracert 10.23.42.96`, the command shows me the first hop and the intended gateway (10.23.42.97). If I run `tracert 10.41.73.1` **sometimes** it goes through the correct gateway and **sometimes** it just times out.
If I run the command twice in a row, it's very likely that I will see two different outcomes.

Am I missing something? I already set up a system like this on Linux, and it's working without any problems. I am pretty new to networking, expecially under Windows. Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong? Thank you very much.

**EDIT**

Removed partial output of `route print` and added the complete output of `route -p print` and `route print`.

Comment: `route print` and `route -p print` mostly does not give the same output

Comment: Thanks. I edited the original question to include the complete output of both commands.

Comment: Why the third route: `route -p ADD 10.23.42.96  MASK 255.255.255.248 10.23.42.97 IF 17`? As far as I can gather that subnet is `local`, so no need to add a route to it, since it is in the routing table by default.

Comment: I dont'have ```10.23.42.96``` as a default gateway, if I try to trace without having that route in the table, the packet goes through the default ```10.123.11.254```. The weird part is that this one is the **only** route with some consistency. Whenever I trace a packet to ```10.23.42.x``` I get the expected ```10.23.42.97``` gateway result. The other two are ignored 9 times out of 10 (```tracert``` times out every step).